# Grow LVM RAID10?

Tags: raid, mdadm, lvm

RHEL LVM [has supported RAID4/5/6 as of 6.3](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/raid_volumes.html) and RAID10 as of 6.4. It's well-known that mdadm [won't let you `--grow` raid10](https://superuser.com/a/311576/84636), my question is whether this is a limitation of LVM RAID10 too?

If it is possible, what are the downsides of LVM RAID10 versus LVM on top of md RAID10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Gentoo Wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#LVM_RAID10), it is possible in certain circumstances, but probably not desirable:

> It is not possible to RAID10 an existing volume, **nor reshape the RAID10 across more/less PVs**, nor to convert to a different RAID level/linear volume, **It is possible to extend a RAID10 across additional PVs, but they must be added in multiples of the original RAID10** (which will effectively linearly append a new RAID10), **or --alloc anywhere must be specified (which can hurt performance)**. In the above example, 4 additional PVs would be required without --alloc anywhere.

In addition LVM RAID10 is more restricted than the md RAID10 (eg it requires an even number of drives):

> LVM syntax requires the number of PV be multiple of the numbers stripes and mirror, even though RAID10 format does not

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to grow an mdadm raid10 if you have at least linux 3.5 mdadm 3.3 and aren't using the far layout.

Comment: that's interesting, though I meant 'grow' as in 'add more disks.

Comment: @JackDouglas, ahh, right.. It looks like patches to support this were posted to the mailing list in April of 2012, and were merged into the kernel, but it doesn't look like the support was added to mdadm.  I've pinged the mailing list to check but I think it is possible by fiddling with sysfs directly instead of mdadm.

Comment: @JackDouglas, apparently this did make it into mdadm 3.3.

Comment: Wow, yes, ["RAID10 arrays can be reshaped to change the number of devices, change the chunk size, or change the layout between 'near' and 'offset'."](http://lwn.net/Articles/565591/). Not sure when this is going to arrive in RHEL, I suspect not for some time :)

Comment: To be clear, this answer really helps me, but doesn't answer the question about LVM RAID10 directly, which is why I haven't accepted it.

Comment: I experimented with growing mdadm raid10 using mdadm v3.3.2 with mixed results.  I found that I couldn't grow a raid10 that I had created with an earlier version of mdadm.  A raid10 that was created with v3.3, I was able to reshape/grow.